# How do you call "expanding" *args and **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python

In Python you can write something like this:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = {'foo': 'bar'}
my_function(*a, **b)
```

Is there a specific term for what happens in the last line with `a` and `b` and, if yes, what is it? It's not "destructuring" I suppose. And "variable expansion" sounds wrong too.

Comment: It's [*"unpacking"*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: argument unpacking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters